# translate one field of a model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have this model:

```
 class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=400,null=True, blank=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this model objects is created automatically in the views like this

```
def payment_confirmation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = paymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                amount= float(form.cleaned_data['amount'])
                form.save()
                notify = Notification.objects.create(
                    user = request.user,
                    text = f"{amount} $ is added to your wallet",
                )
                trans = _('Recharge Completed successfully')
                messages.success(request,trans)
                return redirect('my_wallet')
        return HttpResponse("completed")
```

I was able to translate messages and static pages but i couldn't find a way to translate this notification text field
i looked some libraries but it seems to translate only the verbose_name of the field and not the value

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def payment_confirmation(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = paymentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            amount= float(form.cleaned_data['amount'])
            form.save()
            notify = Notification.objects.create(
                user = request.user,
                text = _("{} $ is added to your wallet").format(amount),
            )
            trans = _('Recharge Completed successfully')
            messages.success(request,trans)
            return redirect('my_wallet')
    return HttpResponse("completed")
```

Comment: This work fine but you will need to make messages then the language at  translated language.

Comment: with this solution i have to translate every new notification that has a different credit amount from previous ones
because every time the view creates a notification it's different from the others becouse of the different amount in the text field

Answer (score 0):

so what i did is that i added another field to my model

```
text_ar = models.TextField(max_length=400,null=True, blank=True)
```

and added that field to my view with the translated text manually

```
 def payment_confirmation(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = paymentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
            amount= float(form.cleaned_data['amount'])
            form.save()
            notify = Notification.objects.create(
                user = request.user,
                text = f"{amount} $ is added to your wallet",
                text_ar = f" دولار الى محفظتك {amount} تمت اضافة"
            )
            trans = _('Recharge Completed successfully')
            messages.success(request,trans)
            return redirect('my_wallet')
    return HttpResponse("completed")
```

and a simple if statement on the template to check the current language and display the correct text

```
 {% get_current_language as current_language%}
    {% if current_language== 'en' %}{{ notify.text }}{% elif current_language == 'ar' %}{{ notify.text_ar }}{% endif %}
```

it works fine but i don't feel like it's the right way to do it